# how to install jist/swans in windows?

Tags: java

i want to run jist/swans on windows to be able to compile and run via command line

this **didn't** help: http://vanet.info/node/98

source: jist.ece.cornell.edu/sw.html

i would really appreciate any easy to do tutorial on how to do setup this!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try following the guide and then ask a specific question when you have a problem?

Comment: i want to know to make it work, the very basic tutorial to run a hello world for jist/swans. i would like an expert in jist/swans packages

Answer (score 0):

I just want to know what sort of applications are you working in?
I think if you try different simulator like **omnet**++, it will help.they have great, modules that u can add and utilize.